# Пропали некоторые подсказки PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Некоторое время назад `PyCharm` почему-то перестал подсказазывать мне продолжения строк.

Например при импортировании библиотек мне вручную приходиться вбивать их имена.
Но некоторые подсказки работают, например он предлагает мне имена уже использованных переменных.

Как это можно исправить?

Если что у меня операционка `Elementary os`

Comment: обновилось до 2020.3.1?

Comment: @Jack_oS да, уже обновил

Comment: Проблема со всеми библиотеками?

Comment: например в настроенном проекте пишешь from django. и ничего не подсказывает ?

Comment: @gil9red Да, проблема со всеми библиотеками и не только с ними, когда пытаешься обратиться к классу или переменной импортируемой библиотеки подсказок нет

Comment: @inzem77 да.....

Comment: Интерпретатор указан? (правый нижний угол)

Comment: @nomnoms12 Да все указано. Проект запускается и работает, не работают только подсказки

Comment: Попробуй переустановить PyCharm просто.

Comment: да, 2020.3.1 вышла глючная... сделайте downgrade до 2020.2?

Comment: Экономный режим выключен (File - Power Save Mode)?

Comment: @Jack_oS, у меня сейчас PyCharm 2020.3.1 Community открыт, никаких проблем с подсказками не наблюдаю.

Comment: @insolor хорошо вам, а я в 2020.3.1 Pro наблюдаю: `user = CustomUser.objects.all()
    for u in user:
        print(f'{u.first_name}')` : после u. никаких полей не подбрасывает ((

Comment: @Jack_oS к вам аналогичный вопрос: Power Save Mode выключено?

Comment: @insolor выключен, никогда не пользовался даже... я, собственно, из вашего коммента выше и узнал, что есть такой режим ))

Comment: @Jack_oS Я поставил 2020.3.1 professional, это помогло

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Да, переустановка помогла, спасибо)

Comment: @rew и в джанге работает автодополнение?